# What is var name = (param) => {} in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working with a React-Router test stubbing example, and I've never seen this class convention before.  I'm guessing this is ES6 specific?

```
var stubRouterContext = (Component, props, stubs) => {
    function RouterStub() { }

    Object.assign(RouterStub, {
        makePath () {},
        makeHref () {},
        transitionTo () {},
        replaceWith () {},
        goBack () {},
        getCurrentPath () {},
        getCurrentRoutes () {},
        getCurrentPathname () {},
        getCurrentParams () {},
        getCurrentQuery () {},
        isActive () {},
        getRouteAtDepth() {},
        setRouteComponentAtDepth() {}
    }, stubs);

    return React.createClass({
        childContextTypes: {
            router: React.PropTypes.func,
            routeDepth: React.PropTypes.number
        },

        getChildContext () {
            return {
                router: RouterStub,
                routeDepth: 0
            };
        },

        render () {
            return <Component {...props} />
        }
    });
};
```

And why do I get TypeError: object is not function when I do this?

```
var Subject = stubRouterContext(Handler, props);
```

Here's the link to the doc https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/testing.md

Comment: Yes, it is ES6 arrow function syntax, see here https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features

Comment: [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Are you transpiling your code? How?

Comment: Nevermind, this is a duplicate.  @JMM, I was using babel, but I simply forgot to export the module.  Closing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ES6 specific, it's the arrow shorthand: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows

"Arrows are a function shorthand using the `=>` syntax. They are syntactically similar to the related feature in C#, Java 8 and CoffeeScript."